# Nginx - rewrite / to subfolder

Tags: php, nginx

I have a site that use to be on the root level of document root. I am moving it to a subfolderI in the new document root. All the links are absolute (/assets/styles.css, /folder/file.php). My subfolder would be at example.com/sub/. Is there any way I can make Nginx rewrite /assets to example.com/sub/assets?

Answer (score 0):

You should have something like this in your nginx.conf

```
    location /assets {
        root   /var/www/example.com/documentroot/;
        ...
    }
```

which told NginX to fetch "assets" from that directory. Unless I'm mistaken, you should simply edit the root folder in "/var/www/example.com/documentroot/sub/".

Or, you had a whole root there:

```
    location / {
        root   /var/www/example.com/documentroot/;
        index index.php;
        ...
    }
```

Again you just add "sub/" to "documentroot/".

Finally, if you ONLY want to move "assets", edit or add a "location /assets" configuration stanza in nginx.conf.